# How do you stop a /playsound music clip?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you stop music with command blocks?
For example, when I use command

```
  /playsound records.far @p ~ ~ ~10 8.0 1.0 1.0
```

it plays the selected song, in this case *far*, but how do you stop the music if you want to play another song? Because they both play.

Comment: Playrecords is not a vanilla command, what mods are you using?

Comment: No mods it is a command that plays records but sorry the command is /playsound records.far @p ~ ~ ~10 8.0 1.0 1.0    I did not add playsound in my first post I was just making  a quick example of my problem

Comment: That moment when you don't have 10 reputation to make a new post about the 1.9.3 /stopsound command.. D:<

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to pause, or stop a sound file that is playing. That is, you will have to wait for that particular file to be played till its very end. Only then will the two files not merge.

Sometimes, changing gamemode from creative to survival also stops the sound, though I am not completely sure of it.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this on a youtube video here:

Basically you just have to play 45 sounds at once then you'll notice that all other sounds will be canceled out but you'll have to make a blank/custom sound in a resource pack or play like 45 chicken noises at once would work. You'd have to do this with command blocks though but it'd be pretty easy to make a plugin do this if you know how.

Comment: Video in answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but now there is a /stopsound command

Comment: To be more precise, it may be: `/stopsound PlayerName`

Answer (score -2):

Without the use of teleporting to a different location, this is not possible.

Comment: What has teleporting got to do with this problem?

Comment: As in teleporting away from the sound

Answer (score -3):

Just change your Music-Block Sound to 0% and then turn it on again.

Comment: This does not work, the sound does not stop when you turn off your volume. It resumes normally when you turn it on again.